# Login to facebook with Curl in desktop

Tags: php, facebook, curl

Im trying to make an script that remote login in to **facebook** with **curl**. Im making with curl not facebook api or something else. So, I have my **email** and **password** and I want to login. Is there any way that I can do it by Desktop? I saw a lot of scripts that login in to facebook by mobile (`m.facebook`) but when I try to do it by desktop I get the error

> Cookies not enable in this browser.

Is there any way that I can do it?

My code trying to loggin in by desktop facebook:

```
$login_email = 'myemail';
$login_pass = 'mypass';
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.facebook.com/login.php');

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'email='.urlencode($login_email).'&pass='.urlencode($login_pass).'&login=Entrar');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,getcwd () . "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,getcwd () . "cookies.txt");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.3) Gecko/20070309 Firefox/2.0.0.3");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.facebook.com");
$page = curl_exec($ch) or die(curl_error($ch));
var_dump($page);
```

Im really trying to do it by using curl. How can I do that?

Comment: What for? If you want to interact with any users, pages or content on Facebook, you should use their API. Access to their site via any automated tools is explicitly prohibited in their ToS.

Comment: its is for my own study.

Comment: Well then I suggest you “study” on a site that doesn’t actively take measures to prevent what you are trying to do.